az pipelines release list doesn't show release result
After running following command , was expecting to see result of release like succeeded or failed like we see in output of az pipelines build list
az pipelines release list --top 5000

how to fetch status and results of release using above command?

Unlike az pipelines build list, the command az pipelines release list doesn't return the release result.
Same for command az pipelines release show --id, it contains details of the release, but it also doesn't directly show the result of the release.
Please check my answer on similar ticket. For release status, it only has below 4 status as per the doc, it cannot show if the release is completed or not. For example, if the release pipeline is completed successfully, or one stage pending on approve, it's still active status.

For release result, there's no directly value to indicate it's failed or succeeded. Instead, we can check task result in each environment of the release, if there's a failed status, we can treat the release as failed.
Hence, the steps are as below:

Get all release ids for the target release pipeline via rest api Releases - List

For each release, get the release details via rest api Releases - Get Release.

Parse the status of environment and each task result, to determine the release run status and result.


Below is the PowerShell script sample:
# Define the parameters
$organization = "orgname"
$project = "projectname"
$definitionId = "1"  # change to your release definition id
$personalAccessToken = "PAT"

# Create the authorization header
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "",$personalAccessToken)))
$headers = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}


# Define the API endpoint for the release definition
$url = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/release/releases?definitionId=$definitionId" + "&api-version=7.1-preview.8"

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method Get

#check for each release
foreach ($release in $response.value) {
    Write-Host "Release ID: $($release.id)"
    
    # Invoke the REST API to get the release details
    $url2 = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/release/releases/$($release.id)" + "?api-version=7.1"
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url2 -Method Get -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json"

    # output release status:
    Write-Host "Release: $($response.name)"
    Write-Host "Release status: $($response.status)"

    foreach ($environment in $response.environments) { 
        # Get the environment name and status 
        $environmentName = $environment.name 
        $environmentStatus = $environment.status

        # Write-Host "Environment $environmentName has status $environmentStatus"
        if ($environmentStatus -eq "inProgress" -or $environmentStatus -eq "notDeployed" -or $environmentStatus -eq "pending")
        {
        Write-Host "Release is still running"
        break
        }
        # Loop through the tasks in the environment
        foreach ($task in $environment.deploySteps.releaseDeployPhases.deploymentJobs.tasks)
        {
            # Get the task name and status
            $taskName = $task.name
            $taskStatus = $task.status

            # Write the task name and status to the console
            Write-Host "Task $taskName has status $taskStatus"
            if ($taskStatus -eq "failed")
            {
              Write-Host "Release is failed at stage $environmentName task $taskName"    # echo release is failed at which stage and which task.
            }   
        }

    }
    Write-Host  "======Next release======"
}


Script result on my side for your reference:

If you want a direct value to indicate the release result, it's recommended to raise a user voice ticket on community link,thanks.

Thank you for detailed explanation !
So, it means we can't use az pipeline release call for getting the result. Only way to use traditional REST API call to achieve the classic release results. I created a feature request as we are using azure-devops extension and it's supported api call in our projects.

Glad to help, @AshishDadhich!  The az pipeline release call works same with traditional rest api.  The az pipelines release show --id has same result with Releases - Get Release to get the target release details. same way to parse the release result you wanted. There is no direct value to indicate the release result, thanks for your feature request.
